# mid = (low + high) / 2 different answer from mid = low + (high - low) / 2

Tags: java, arrays

I was playing around with code for a binary search and insert.

Given an *array* of *sorted integers*, it should find the index of the target number. If it does not exist, then it should return the index of where it would be if inserted.

I found that the way I compute the `mid` causes my code to work differently.

I'm wondering if there is some difference between `mid = (low + high) / 2` and `mid = low + (high - low) / 2`.

An input example:  array `[1,3,5,6]` and a target value is `2`.

```
    public static int searchInsert(int[] nums, int target) {
        int high = nums.length - 1;
        int low = 0;
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2; // diff if use: (low + high) / 2
        
        for( ; low <= high ; ) {
            if(nums[mid] > target) {
                high = mid - 1;
            } else if(nums[mid] < target) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                return mid;
            }
            mid = low + (high - low) / 2;  // diff if use: (low + high) / 2

            System.out.println(low + (high - low) / 2 + ": " + high + " " + low);
            System.out.println(mid + " " + high + " " + low);
        }
        return mid;
    }
```

Comment: Well which values of `high` and `low` are you seeing a difference for? (I can easily imagine some cases where they'd be different, but it would be useful if you could provide a concrete example...)

Comment: Remember that integer arithmetic doesn't preserve fractions, it drops them.  You should be able to work out which numbers for low and high will give you different answers. (Hint: look at odd numbers, even numbers have no fraction to drop.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I added the example inputs

Comment: @markspace right in that case both of them should drop the decimals, what I'm seeing is that one of them returns a 1 for a result of 0.5 and the other returns a 0

Comment: Nope, in one case you divide first, then add.  In the other you add first.  Those will produce different answer if both numbers are odd.

Comment: @markspace the value of low is 1 and the value of high is 0 when the loop ends, using the formula this would give 0.5 and the .5 is dropped so shouldn't it still be 0 instead of 1?

Comment: I don't think that's the actual problem.  You might want to be more explicit about what differences during execution you see.  Include output from your program, and explain where you think the output should be different.

Comment: you do `mid = low + (high - low) / 2` also when `high < low`, and since integer division truncates the fractional part _towards zero_, you get a different result than if you did `(low + high) / 2`

Comment: You haven't provided concrete examples of *just* `high` and `low`, where the two expressions differ. The searching part is irrelevant to a large extent - that's just how you happen to have got to those values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference (with your example of numbers) is:

In one point (last loop iteration) you have `low = 1` and `high = 0`.

In this case the formula `(low + high) / 2` comes out to `(1 + 0) / 2`, this is `1 / 2` and this evaluates to `0` (integer arithmetic).

But the formula `low + (high - low) / 2` comes out to `1 + (0 - 1) / 2`, this is `1 + (-1 / 2)` and further `1 + 0` because -1 / 2 is also 0 in integer arithmetic.

If you would have floating point steps it would boil down to `(int) (1.0 / 2.0)` vs. `(int) 1.0 + (int)(-1.0 / 2.0)`